# XMLHttpRequest Posting empty body

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

When I try to post some data to my backend API service I use the `XMLHttpRequest` object, but when I try to send the data with `ajax.send` it sent nothing to the server

Code snipper:

```
ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.open("POST", "https://someapi.com",true);
ajax.send({
  name: "Name",
  phone: "123468375698563897569575863"
});

ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){

    if(ajax.readyState==4){
        JSONback = JSON.parse(ajax.response);
        console.log(JSONback);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly send a JS object over the wire.

You need to convert it to a string first, just like you need to parse it when you're getting it back.

```
ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.open("POST", "https://balbalbal.com", true);
ajax.send(
  JSON.stringify({
    name: "Name",
    phone: "123468375698563897569575863"
  })
);

ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if(ajax.readyState==4){
    JSONback = JSON.parse(ajax.response);
    console.log(JSONback);
  }
};
```

The simplest PHP test code on the server side would be:

```
<?php
  echo file_get_contents('php://input');
?>
```

And here is a slightly more advanced example that will decode it, add a new field and send it back:

```
<?php
  $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
  $object = json_decode($json);
  $object->id = 123;

  echo json_encode($object);
?>
```

Comment: And this time i event not get the JSON back from the server

Comment: What are you doing on the server side? Which language are you using?

Comment: I'm using PHP as my server side language,and this is my API project i'm making,and my docs already contain jQuery,and i just want to add plain old JS code too,and also i'm learning JS

Comment: Please see my updated answer for the correct way to read the JSON string. I suspect you might be trying to get it from `$_POST`.

Comment: can you me in some in some kid of stuff like Gitter,because i want to sync the code with you,if you want

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

1. Say you are sending JSON
2. Convert your JavaScript data structure into JSON

Such:

```
var data = {
    name: "Name",
    phone: "123468375698563897569575863"
};

var json = JSON.stringify(data);

var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.open("POST", "https://balbalbal.com", true);
ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
ajax.send(json);
```

Comment: And this time i event not get the JSON back from the server

Comment: @FelixFong — Well, that's still how you send JSON. If you aren't getting JSON back then there could be lots of reasons for it. Maybe you are making a cross-origin request and running into the same origin policy. Maybe the URL doesn't accept JSON formatted POST requests. Maybe you simply have the URL wrong. Maybe a bunch of other things. Use the Network and Console tabs in your browser's developer tools to debug it.

Comment: To be hones,that is my API docs example,i already got jQuery siting at my docs page,but now i just want to add one more way to show the dev show to using plain old JS and play with my API,and the biggest problem i got is i'm new to JS,but i do know how to use jQuery very well like many others

Comment: @FelixFong — Justifying to me why you want to do this isn't going to help you debug it.

Comment: This is when i use JS http://image.prntscr.com/image/a48113d4b3dd4168914d95e03c735baa.png , and i try to debug,so i add the debug object to show me what i just send to the server,and that is what i get using jQuery(working) http://image.prntscr.com/image/12d99a5807e641ca97a4c48ef8f2db81.png